# Scheduling tasks while my app is closed

Tags: java, android

Exmaple scenario:

My app user scaduales a certain task to excecute in an hour from now.

The user closes the app.

How does the app know when to excecute the job? how can i Schedule a progran to run every x time?

Also, What is the right practice - make the app main program (with UI) and the background process saparate or be the same program (considering the background program dont change UI)?

Thanks

Comment: A very useful approach to solving problems like this is to ask "what common thing is functionally similar to what I want to do?" and then look at an example.  In this case, I think you'd learn a lot from finding an Alarm Clock example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i Schedule a progran to run every x time?

[Use `AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

> What is the right practice - make the app main program (with UI) and the background process saparate or be the same program

Please make it be the same program.